# Laravel CSS Loading Slowly

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I am developing a website with laravel 9. My home page is styling after style pages are loaded, eventhough the css files are minimized.

This is the first time page is loaded:

[image]

After 1 second:

[image]

The head file :

```html
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href=".././assets/imgs/theme/favicon.svg" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/main.css")}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/plugins/animate.min.css")}}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset("css/extrac.css")}}" />
```

and index.blade.php

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="tr">
    
    <head>
        <title>Giriş Yap </title>
    
        @include('front.layouts.head')
    
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        @include('front.layouts.header')
    
        <!--End header-->
        <main class="main pages">
   

    ....
```

The network loading graphs:

[image]

What should i do? It is getting annoying...

Comment: Did you try `php artisan optimize:clear`?

Comment: Yeah, but it didn't work

Comment: remove css files one by one and see which one is causing the problem

Comment: do you try to ```atisan optimize``` and ```clear your browser history```?

Comment: There are various reasons that may cause the issue. `browser caching setting` , `application caching` , ... . You need to check one by one to debug this kind of issues

Comment: I've clear the browser caches and used `php artisan optimize` and `php artisan optimize:clear`. But nothing is working. Same issue goes.

Comment: I think it is because of my local server. When I moved my project to the public, everything worked perfectly.